# How to set current_path in Capistrano 3

Tags: capistrano3

Is there a way to set the current path folder in Capistrano3.

I can see it's now part of the [Capistrano::DSL::Paths](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/capistrano/3.0.0/symbols/Capistrano::DSL::Paths#line=15) module but I'm not sure how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with something like this

```
set :current_path, "/somecurrentpathyouwant"

namespace :deploy do

  desc "Create symlink to configured current path"
  task :create_symlink do
    on roles(:all) do
      execute "rm -f #{fetch(:current_path)} && ln -s #{release_path} #{fetch(:current_path)}"
    end
  end

end

after :deploy, "deploy:create_symlink"
```